# How to check if a JWT Token has expired without throw exceptions?

Tags: java, spring, string, jwt, token

I'm developing a Java application (using Spring Boot) and I need some help:
This application receives as input a **JWT token** which I process in a method. The method for now is the following:

```
private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken myMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    
    // Code that gets the 'token' String

    try{
    
    Map<String, String> registry = ((Map<String, String>) (token.getBody().get("registry")));
    String sub = ((String) (parsedToken.getBody().get("sub")));


    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken finalToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(sub, null, null);
                            
            
    return finalToken; 

            
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException exception) { // Only here I have the certainty that the token has expired!
            // Code that handles the exception
    }
```

}

However, I need to implement a logic that must check in several places whether the token obtained has expired or not, **without running this method every time**. The only way I have to know if `token` has expired is the exception raised by `ExpiredJwtException`.

Is there any way to know **if the token has expired without going through the catched exception**? For example, it would be very useful if there was a "token" class that has an `.isExpired` attribute, or something like that.

I don't want to go into handling the exception because it means that I would always depend on the (long) code of the `try` block every time I need to check if a token has expired or not, and I don't want it to be.

Comment: I believe I have written all the code possible to make the question clear

Comment: Okey fair enough

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use a different JWT library, you can do it easily enough.  The [auth0 JWT library](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) has methods to parse and, optionally, verify the token:

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;


DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
if( jwt.getExpiresAt().before(new Date())) {
    System.out.println("token is expired");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can create another class for handling the token validation like below, in the class you will handle the ExpiredJwtException and give the extracted value back , other exceptions will throw it from the class

```
public class TokenValidator {
    Boolean tokenExpired = true;
    public boolean isTokenValid(String token) throws Exception {
        validateToken(token);
        return tokenExpired;
    }

    public Map<String,String> getExtractedData(String token) throws Exception {
        return validateToken(token);
    }

    private Map<String, String> validateToken (String token) throws Exception{
        try {
            Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("jwtSecretKey")
                    .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
            tokenExpired = false;
            return getClaimsInMap(claims);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            DefaultClaims claims = (DefaultClaims) ex.getClaims();
            return getClaimsInMap(claims);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
    private Map<String,String> getClaimsInMap(Claims claims) {
        Map<String,String> expectedMap = new HashMap<>();
        claims.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> expectedMap.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue().toString()));
        return expectedMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using claims. Below sample code can help.

```
// Get Expiration and compare it with new Date()

public boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
}


public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
}


public <T> T extractClaim(String token , Function<Claims, T> claimResolver) {
    final Claims claim= extractAllClaims(token);
    return claimResolver.apply(claim);
}


private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
}
```

Comment: This won't work because `parseClaimsJws` will throw `io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException` before you get a chance to extract the expiration date.
You'll still have to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create additional util method like this:

```
public boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    try {
        return getExpirationDateFromToken(token).before(new Date());
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This what helped me [token has expired](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException)

```
jwtToken = authHeader.substring(7);
    try {
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwtToken); //extract user email from JWT token
        if(userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwtToken, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException eje) {
        log.info("Security exception for user {} - {}",
                eje.getClaims().getSubject(), eje.getMessage());

        log.trace("Security exception trace: {}", eje);
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
```